# VBA DLOOKUP() Date/Time but only compare on Time

Tags: vba

I have this script to get the data less than or equal the time `11:59:00 AM`:

```
Me.lbl001.Caption = Format(DLookup("DateTime", "tblTime", "[ID]=" & Me.txtMacID & " AND [DateTime]<=#5/2/2017 11:59:00 AM#), "hh:mm:ss")
```

But it affects the Date so I'm also getting the data of `5/1/2017` and less. I'm trying to achieve getting data less than `11:59:00 AM` within `5/2/2017` only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Format(DMax("DateTime", "tblTime", "[ID]=" & Me.txtMacID & " AND DateValue([DateTime])=#2/5/2017#"), "hh:mm:ss")
```